# Build timestamp using Hudson and Maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, hudson

From where is the build time set in a project built with Maven and Hudson?

Comment: Which build time do you mean? Which is in the environment or the displayed by Hudson?

Comment: The date of creation for the output jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.keyboardsamurais.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-timestamp-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <configuration>
    <propertyName>timestamp</propertyName>
    <timestampPattern>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm</timestampPattern>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <goals>
      <goal>create</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found that is the time set on the machine Hudson works.